# Prefix Static Library iOS

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I'm building an iOS static library (as per https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework). I depend on SBJson and AFNetworking. I would like to include these libraries to avoid version issues and for installation simplicity; to do so, I need to prefix these libraries to avoid naming conflicts.

How can I prefix other static libraries in a simple way?

Ideally, it would be part of my build process. Less ideally, but acceptable, are tips on how to refactor and rename in a sane manner.

Comment: I will also be using CocoaPods so they handle the dependencies for those who have it, but would like to be able to distribute a non-CocoaPods framework.

Comment: One word: DONT! There is nothing wrong in having external dependancies.

Comment: It seems to me that alot of frameworks do this to make installation easier. One example: Dropbox renamed SBJson to DBJson.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do it. A careful find and replace has worked in the past for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only safe solution (other than not doing this at all) is to build any dependencies with a prefix on all symbols.

The easiest method of prefixing is the classic "find-and-replace". This is error-prone, so it's a good idea to hit the .a with `nm -a` and scour the results for any non-prefixed symbols.

A second, much safer method is to use a two-pass compilation process.

- The first pass builds the dependent project and runs `nm` to dump all symbols into a header file.
- The second pass builds the dependent project again, but this time with the generated prefix header file imported in the precompiled header. This prefix header must be used anywhere you reference symbols from the dependency in your framework in order to properly refer to the renamed symbols.

> For reference, we use this with [Nimbus](http://nimbuskit.info/) to generate the Nimbus prefix headers:
>   https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/scripts/generate_namespace_header
>
> This allows you to distribute a .framework with a prefixed version of Nimbus embedded.

You can now link the resulting .a into your framework and safely avoid any linker conflicts when a third party developer inevitably links their own version of the dependency into their project.

Comment: This is great, as is your iOS-Framework repo. It'd be awesome if you could add this to that repo in some way as well. Thanks a lot for both!

Comment: I'd like to see a section on this, with a little more detail for the beginner in mind.

Comment: I wrote up an article that explores this topic in a bit more detail if any are interested: http://pdx.esri.com/blog/2013/12/13/namespacing-dependencies/

Comment: Your write up is awesome, although I did find that it doesn't quite work when your external dependencies were other .a libraries. It doesn't actually link all of those symbols from the .a's into your ext target, been trying to come up with a way around that.

Comment: Please see the new FAQ answer to [How do I include Third-Party Libraries in my Framework?](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#how-do-i-include-third-party-libraries-in-my-framework) for details on this.

Comment: @featherless: slight bug with your namespace generation: in your string namespacing, you exclude based on ".eh". Because grep takes in regexes, this will match on any string containing eh in the middle of it. The period needs to be escaped to match correctly. That aside, the script works wonderfully.

Comment: Does the Nimbus solution also namespace category methods?

Comment: @aranasaurus I spent quite sometime to follow your blog, but didn't get it working. It will be great if you can provide a sample project. Thanks