# Filter unwanted symbols when prefixing static library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal, static-libraries

I'm trying to prefix a PayPal static library so clients implementing our framework are able to use a different version of it. I've been following [this article](http://pdx.esri.com/blog/2013/12/13/namespacing-dependencies/)  and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512291/prefix-static-library-ios/19341366#19341366) but I'm having some issues.

1. I created a target and added libPayPalMobile.a to Link with binary libraries.
2. I've added the [run script](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/scripts/generate_namespace_header) that has been mentioned in the tutorials above.
3. I've added my target as a dependency to the project.

After `NamespacedDependencies.h` gets generated, I'm seeing some unwanted symbols in the Externs section:

```
// Externs
#ifndef k1PasswordButtonWidth
#define k1PasswordButtonWidth __NS_SYMBOL(k1PasswordButtonWidth)
#endif

#ifndef k1PasswordButtonRightMargin
#define k1PasswordButtonRightMargin __NS_SYMBOL(k1PasswordButtonRightMargin)
#endif

l002
l003
l004
l003
l004
l005
l006
l001
l007
l002
l008
l003
l009
l010
l007
l011
l004
l012
l008
l009
l005
l010
l011
l003
l012
l004
l003
l005
l013
l003
l006
l004
l014
l003
l015
l007
l004
l016
l004
l008
l001
l005
l005
l002
...
```

I figured I could remove these using `grep -v "l[0-9]{0,5}"` but they seem to be dumped with the above symbols, meaning I can't simply filter out these.

Obviously, the problem is that I can't even compile since I'm getting `Parse Issue: Unknown type name l002`.

Any idea what these evil things are and how to get rid of them?

EDIT:
This is Externs part of the script:

```
echo "// Externs" >> $header

nm $CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH | sort | uniq | grep " D " | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -v "\$_NS" | grep -v "\$_UI" | sed -e 's/_\(.*\)/#ifndef \1\'$'\n''#define \1 __NS_SYMBOL(\1)\'$'\n''#endif\'$'\n''/g' >> $header

nm $CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH | sort | uniq | grep " S " | cut -d' ' -f3 | grep -v "\$_NS" | grep -v ".eh" | grep -v "\$_UI" | grep -v "OBJC_" | sed -e 's/_\(.*\)/#ifndef \1\'$'\n''#define \1 __NS_SYMBOL(\1)\'$'\n''#endif\'$'\n''/g' >> $header
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to distribute the PayPal library as part of your own, I'd encourage you to express a dependency so that developers always get the latest version.

I'd also encourage you to use the [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK), or better yet, the Braintree SDK (which includes PayPal) rather than the obsolete MPL. Both Braintree and the iOS SDKs publish to Cocoapds to ease dependency management.

Comment: I understand your approach. Although, we'd have to force developers to use the latest version of PayPal SDK. Some of the applications that are integrating our framework are pretty old and we'd like to avoid forcing devs to make changes to their root application.

Comment: Maintaining support for older integrations makes sense. However, feature development has stopped on older SDKs & APIs, so those integrations won't get the benefit of updated user experiences. I'd hate to see new integrations go down that path as well.