# How to use #import <> on a git submodule

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, cocoapods

I am including two libraries in my project. Since my project is a static library I decided to include the libs via git submodules rather than cocoa pods.

LibraryA has a dependency on LibraryB and imports it via `#import <>`, which gives me a file not found error.

I added `/path/to/folder/with/my/submodules` in both the framework and header search paths of my target, but the only way I've been able to resolve the error is by changing LibraryA to use `#import ""`.

Is there a proper way to fix this that does not involve forking LibraryA and changing the import statement myself?

Comment: Are these libraries created as `Frameworks`? They need to be copied into `Frameworks` as a build phase.

Comment: They are not frameworks, which is exactly why I am having this issue. I am using `JVFloatLabeledTextField`, which in turn requires `HTAutocompleteTextField`. I added the relevant source files to my project manually.

Comment: You can create your own `Frameworks`; that's what I was getting at. If you add them that way then it's very easy to use the `#import < >` format. You shouldn't have to set anything in the frameworks path or header search paths either. I only use `< >` when linking a dynamic library, anything static I use `""`.

Comment: Thats generally a very good point. But I've had issues in the past when I tried to bundle a framework into a static library the way you suggest. AFAIK that could also lead to namespace collisions if any 3rd party app that uses my static lib also uses `JVFloatLabeledTextField` or `HTAutocompleteTextField`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: As long as things are handled properly with static libraries namespace collisions shouldn't happen. Maybe it's easier said than done, since static libraries can be a real pain to deal with on many levels. Using prefixed symbols when building your lib ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19341366/499581)), or declaring external dependencies and letting your users deal with them. Apple has some good tips and best practices for doing things in a sensible manner, so you might want to have a look. At least you now have the option of choosing between using a static or dynamic library now.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=416 | https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkBinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002256-BAJICBDD (Apple needs to update their documentation, but much of the same principles they talk about for OSX would apply for iOS)

Answer (score 0):

If your app name is MyApp and your submodule is MySubmodule then go in the build settings for the app target and put this for the "Header Search Paths":

```
MyApp/MySubmodule
```

Hopefully inside your submodule you have another dir that matches the MySubmodule name but here I'll just say it is SDKName:

```
#include <SDKName/UmbrellaHeader.h>
```

What happens is it now searches the root of the MySubmodule path and since the SDKName is a subfolder now you can use the <> syntax.